# Induced subgraph is a trail of length $2r-1$

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

> Let $G$ be a simple connected graph of radius $r$. Prove that we can find $2r-1$ vertices such that their induced subgraph is a trail.

I've tried induction on $V(G)$, but haven't really made progress. The equality case occurs when $G$ is a complete graph, but I'm not sure what to make of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FWIW, here's a solution I found to this problem.

Let $H$ be a subgraph of $G$ with the same radius but the minimal number of vertices. We show that the result holds in $H$.

Let $v_r$ be a leaf of a spanning tree of $H$. The minimality of $H$ implies that the radius of $H-v_r$ has radius less than $r$. Thus there is a vertex $v_0$ such that $d(v_0,u)\leq r-1$ for all $u\in H-v_r$. Then $d(v_0,v_r)=r$, so let $v_0,v_1,v_2,\dots,v_r$ be the path joining $v_0,v_r$.

Suppose that $r\geq3$ (the other case is trivial). Choose $x$ such that $d(v_2,x)=r$: then $x$ is distinct from the $v_i$'s and $d(v_0,x)\leq r-1$.

Let $P$ be the shortest path joining $v_0$ and $x$. Let $w$ be a vertex of $P$. Suppose that $d(w,v_k)=1$ for some $k\geq2$. By the triangle inequality, $$\begin{align*}k&=d(v_0,v_k)\leq d(v_0,w)+1\\r&=d(v_2,x)\leq d(v_2,v_k)+d(v_k,w)+d(w,x)=d(w,x)+k-1.\end{align*}$$Adding these inequalities, $r\leq d(v_0,w)+d(w,x)=d(v_0,x)\leq r-1$, contradiction. Hence no $v_i$ lies on $P$, for $i\geq1$.

Choose $w$ on $P$ adjacent to $v_1$. By the triangle inequality, $$r=d(v_2,x)\leq d(v_2,v_1)+d(v_1,w)+d(w,x)=d(w,x)+2.$$Then $x,\dots,w,v_1,v_2,\dots,v_r$ is the required path.

Comment: There are several minor mistakes. Graph $H$ should be induced subgraph of $G$. Vertex $v_1$ may belong to $P$. Vertex $w$ should be the closest to $x$ from all vertices of $P$ adjacent to $v_1$ for the sake of result being an induced trail. And the last one is that your trail may be longer than you need. Anyway your idea is great. My approach had much more cases and thereby was not finished.